# publish_actions issues

Tags: facebook, oauth

i have adapted my app to all the new features from timeline, aggregations, mini stories and such. i set "publish_actions" as required in the oauth process as well as in the "new auth" process dialog. i have set up my aggregations and everything looks neat an all and i also got the opengraph near realtime ministories working.

BUT

1) i do not get the new auth page to show up ... i am the only developer, i have set "use new auth page" in app settings, i am in the developer beta and got the timeline in my profile of course, i got the near realtime opengraph stories working, i got my aggregations set, i can preview the oauth screen as myself and generic user fine.

2) the old auth page only shows "publish_actions" when i set my app to be of the app-type "games" and when i set my app to be of the type "other" i do not get prompted for "publish_actions" permission when adding the app and i get "OAuth "Facebook Platform" "insufficient_scope" "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions" all the time.

why does developing for/on facebook have to be so buggy and hard all the time?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  What's required to be able to ask for publish_actions?  When I request this permission, the oauth/dialog URL just redirects to the redirect_uri immediately without showing me a dialog or asking permission.

What do I need to set up in my facebook app config to get this to work properly?

Comment: are you using oauth as your authentication type when you load the facebook SDK?

Answer (score 2):

"These stories can only be published by apps categorized as ‘Games’ and are only shown to users when playing a game. We intend to broaden the types of apps that can use these new APIs in the near future." ( http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/ )

So I think we only have two choices right now. Change the app category to "Games" OR Using the new permissions dialog page.

Answer (score 0):

Bump. I have same issue as well.
Created new App, setup everything including new Auth dialog and publish_actions but getting old dialog instead.

I saw someone mentioning that all users should be at least Testers. Tried that and still doesnt work.

**Woohoo, I just changed App type to the "Games" and in Auth dialog it showed now "Add to timeline". It still shows old Auth dialog for me but at least publish_actions is there.**

Comment: Could you help me out and explain what you mean by "old dialog" and "new dialog"? I'm new to FB development and do not understand this difference yet. Thanks

Comment: Im kinda new to this as well but here is what I know. Before Open Graph, FB had Auth dialog/page that would ask user if user wants to grant permission for the app to do certain things. But with new Open graph, they introduced new type of the Auth dialog. You can configure it in your App admin screen. My understanding that this new dialog should be displayed if your app uses new Open Grapth features (like publishing actions on timeline). Right now I see old style dialog even tho my app uses publish_actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same problem. 
I cannot find a way to get 'publish_actions' permissions for an app user.
I've even tried to use directly  which should automatically add 'publish_actions', but the auth dialog just flash and disappear.

This is certainly something linked to the new auth dialog which does not show up even when the correct migration settings are selected.
Is it a Facebook bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the issues you're having. This was a bug on our end and should be resolved later today.